# Unable to bind to a collection of my ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

All - Trying to do 2 things: I have a simple app and am trying to bind my Viewmodel collection to my view. Have 2 approaches in mind but am getting stuck on both of them:

Approach 1: Using Grid as a container to bind the textblock property.

Approach 2: Binding an attribute of the object directly to a textblock on my view (not using grid as a container and its Datacontext property)

**Rule_Model_1.cs**

```
public class Rule_Model_1
{
    public string topMessage { get; set; }
    public List<string> recipients { get; set; }
    public string bottomMessage { get; set; }
    public string hypLink { get; set; }
    public OCCBlock blockType { get; set; }

    public enum OCCBlock
    {
        HardBlock,
        SoftBlock,
        ModifyAndSend
    }
}
```

**Rule_VM_1.cs**

```
class Rule_VM_1
{
    #region Properties
    public List<Rule_Model_1> rule { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public Rule_VM_1()
    {
        #region Initializing a Rule
        rule = new List<Rule_Model_1>();

        rule.Add(new Rule_Model_1()
        {
            topMessage = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
            recipients = new List<string> {"pr@hotmail.com", "pra@gmail.com"},
            bottomMessage = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            hypLink = "http://www.abc.com",
            blockType = Rule_Model_1.OCCBlock.HardBlock
        });
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Rule_UI.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Rule_UI_1 : UserControl
{
    Rule_VM_1 rulevm1;
    public Rule_UI_1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        rulevm1 = new Rule_VM_1();
        DataContext = rulevm1; 
    }
}
```

**Rule_UI.xaml**

```
  <UserControl x:Class="OCC_WPF_POC.Rule_UI_1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<GroupBox Header="Rule Details">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <Grid Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding rule}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding topmessage}" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

The view still shows nothing. Also as mentioned above - how do i have both the approaches working? Any code samples is greatly appreciated

Image Attached[image: Window Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need a list view to bind to a collection property (`rule`).  This should work:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding rule}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding topmessage}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

To bind to the grid, you can set the `DataContext` using an indexer `[]`:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding rule[0]}">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding topmessage}" />
</Grid>
```

And without the Grid:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding rule[0].topmessage}" />
```

Comment: right - i had it working with listbox but in this case - really dont need a listbox - its 3 textblocks on the screen (which can be contained within a grid). Attaching a screenshot shortly

Comment: @Patrick gotcha, please see my edit.  You just need to update the `DataContext` in the grid, and it should work as is.

Comment: just did that..doesnt load the data :(

Comment: tried both the options - but (with and without the grid) - doesnt seem to display any data

Comment: Ok - trying again. seems to work...just cleaning the solution and rebuilding seems to have helped :(. the grid solution is working perfectly fine now. Also trying the textblock solution !!

Thanks dbaseman !!!